# Will my apps be removed from the App Store if my developer account expires?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Will my apps get taken down on the App Store if I allow my developer account to expire?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes - all your apps will be removed from their respective App Stores if your developer program membership expires.

> If your Apple Developer Program membership expires, you will still have access to iTunes Connect. However, your apps will no longer be available for download on the App Store and you will not be able to submit new apps or updates.

<sup>Source: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/itunes-connect/</sup>

Attempting to log in to iTunes Connect will show the following message, but all of the services are still accessible.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your app will be deleted from the App Store until you renew your subscription.

Comment: Don't worry. I posted my answer and went to apple developer to find out the cite that was posted in the other answer.

Comment: Do you know what happens in this case? Are the apps still "approved" in the system or do you have to regenerate App ID's and resubmit apps for approval? _(my guess is there is a period where you can reactivate things gracefully, but after a time, you have to start over or get personal help to reactivate the account from iTunes Connect Support)_

Comment: @bmike I forgot I had access to an account that has expired. It expired in February 2014 and the account has not been removed from iTunes Connect yet, with all the App IDs still listed and binaries available. I can always check the account every couple of years to see what happens to it!

Comment: @grgarside woah - that's unexpected. Are they paid apps or free apps or a mix? binaries avalaibale to a logged in developer account or available to the public?

Comment: 5 years on what happened?